# Why my .bb class is not working on input tag?

Tags: html, css, class

[image: CSS and HTML]
I want the input border to be green when I add a class "bb" to the  tag.
when I define class in CSS as "input.bb" and add class "bb" to my HTML  tag it works.

I want to be able to define class by just ".bb" and add class "bb" to my HTML  tag, but it won't work.
I am new at this, it should work as it does for the  tag. Thank you for your help.

```
.bb{
    border-color:var(--success-color);
}

<div class="field">
    <label class="field-title">Re-enter Password</label>
    <input class="bb" type="password" placeholder="Re-enter Password">  
    <small >Error message</small>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to something called *specificity*, which I will admit is one of the trickier concepts in CSS.  You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

The short story is that it gives every css rule a weight and when two rules are in conflict the one that *weighs* the most wins out.

In your linked css you have the following two rules that set the border of an input element

```css
.form input { }
.bb { }
```

The weight of is 11 (10 from the class, 1 from the element) and the second is 10 (just a class). This means that the first rule will be more specific and wins out: your border gets the color from that declaration.